# Postgresql - Copying a column between two tables when the value of another column matches

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am still new to postgres and dealing with databases in general. What I am trying to do is the following:

I have two tables (*bulk*, and *selected*). There is an *id* column in each of the tables, and there is a column called *name* in the *selected* table.

What I am trying to do is to compare the values of the *id* in both tables and when it matches, copy the value of the *name* from the second table to a new column in the first table. Otherwise the value should remain *NULL*. The new column is already created and ready to receive the data. I tried the following:

```
select id,
  CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from selected where bulk.id = selected.id) THEN selected.names
    ELSE NULL
    END
AS name
FROM bulk;
```

I'm not sure if this completely does not make sense, but this is the closest thing I could get after researching. When I run this I am getting the following error: [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table selected

The error is self-explanatory, but I don't know how to solve it

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to select the data that way or do you want to update the data in the table?

Comment: I want to update. Basically copying the name from selected to bulk when the id match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the column, then use `update`.  I'm a bit lost on which table needs to be updated, but something like this:

```
update secondtable t2
        set name = t1.name
    from firsttable t1
    where t2.id = t1.id;
```

As for your `select`, you would do:

```
select b.id,
       (select s.name from selected s where b.id = s.id) as name
from bulk b;
```

You don't need the `case`.  If there is no match, then the returned value is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I'm getting syntax error when I am trying the update code you provided. just before the second line. I tried to add a SET before name, but then I got an error at the last line just before the on

Comment: Gordon's code has some syntax errors. You do need `SET` and you will need to change `ON` to `WHERE` in his code. (I've edited his answer with these corrections)

Comment: Thanks Nicarus.
Yea I'm already trying that. But I am dealing with a very huge database so it is still processing the query so far. 
I will update the answer once I make sure it worked